# Win10 upgrade to version 20H2 failed - how to determine the cause?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-upgrade

**Question**:
Where can I find logs from Win10 upgrade and how to interpret them? I've attempted to apply the upgrade three times, and I'm trying to get a clue if there's anything I can fix, so that it succeeds next time. In particular, if the failures are caused by an incompatible driver, a HW error, by missing files or dirs, I can try to fix that.

**Details:**
Windows Update offered me Win10 upgrade from version 1909 to 20H2. The upgrade failed - twice - with error 0x8007001f. Then Windows Update stopped offering the upgrade. Hence, the third time I used the [Upgrade Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), but the upgrade failed again. By "failing" I mean that the update had been installed, the Windows rebooted and was finishing the installation, but at the end everything was rolled back. (One round took about an hour.)

I was able to find some logs in `C:\Windows\Panther\NewOs`, but these logs are from the second upgrade attempt only. I cannot find any logs from the third attempt, they seem to be lost/rolled back. In the Windows Event logs, there is a single line: installation failed with error 0x8007001f, nothing else. Should I look somewhere else?

The `setupact.log` in `C:\Windows\Panther\NewOs\Panther` contains 450 error lines in total, but this is probably normal as the installation went on. Most of the errors are in `setuperr.log`, too. I cannot tell what error caused the installation to stop and roll back. These are the last errors (with several important Info lines):

```
                     Info                  SP     SPExecuteFirstBootApply: Begin run. WinOld: C:\Windows.old
                     Info                  SP     pSPExecuteApply: Starting the engine online
2020-11-15 11:15:55, Error                 MIG    Ignoring replacement manifest with no settingsVersionRange or versionRange attribute in migration element: Microsoft-Windows-Container-Manager
2020-11-15 11:16:03, Error      [0x080831] MIG    CSIAgent: Invalid xml format: FormatException: Component with display name: Plugin/{C939EC0F-2F56-4CE8-AF56-2336596A5FA7} already loaded __cdecl Mig::CMXEMigrationXml::CMXEMigrationXml(class Mig::CPlatform *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::XmlDocument *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::String *)
2020-11-15 11:16:04, Error                        Mig::CUpgradeTransportPlatform::SetUserContext: Store platform failed to find the user with ID: USER00000005, SID: S-1-0-0[gle=0x000000cb]
2020-11-15 11:16:04, Error                 MIG    Mig::CKnowledgeManager::BeginProcessingContext: Source platform failed to set the user context USER00000005[gle=0x000000cb]
2020-11-15 11:16:04, Error                        MigApply caught exception: Win32Exception: Can't switch to requested user context: USER00000005.: A device attached to the system is not functioning. [0x0000001F] int __cdecl Mig::CKnowledgeManager::Apply(class Mig::CPlatform *,class Mig::CPlatform *,class Mig::CPlatform *,class Mig::CUserMappingList *,class UnBCL::Hashtable<class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::String *> *,class Mig::CAgentManager *,class Mig::CMigrationLogger *,int *,struct IMigExecuteProgress *)[gle=0x000000cb]
2020-11-15 11:16:04, Error                 SP     pSPExecuteApply: Apply operation failed. Error: 0x00000004[gle=0x000000cb]
                     Info                  SP     SPExecuteFirstBootApply: End run. Result: 0x00000004
2020-11-15 11:16:05, Error                 SP     Apply (first boot apply, online phase): Migration phase failed. Result: 4, no specific error[gle=0x00000002]
2020-11-15 11:16:05, Error                 SP     Operation failed: First boot apply. Error: 0x8007001F[gle=0x000000b7]
2020-11-15 11:16:05, Error                 SP     Operation execution failed: 13. hr = 0x8007001F
2020-11-15 11:16:05, Error                 SP     ExecuteOperations: Failed execution phase Post First Boot. Error: 0x8007001F
2020-11-15 11:16:05, Error                 SP     Operation execution failed.
2020-11-15 11:16:05, Error                 SP     CSetupPlatformPrivate::Execute: Failed to deserialize/execute post-FirstBoot operations. Error: 0x8007001F
```

Was the upgrade failure caused by the error `Store platform failed to find the user with ID: USER00000005, SID: S-1-0-0 (Nobody)`? In that case I'd have to wait for the fix by Microsoft.

**Edit:**
SetupDiag found the logs from the third attempt in `C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther`. It tested plenty of thing, most of them were "No match", unfortunately it found nothing. Here is the content of the `SetupDiagResults.log`:

```
Matching Profile found: FindRollbackFailure - 3A43C9B5-05B3-4F7C-A955-88F991BB5A48
SetupDiag version: 1.6.0.0
System Information:
    Machine Name = XXXXX
    Manufacturer = LENOVO
    Model = 20MAS0P900
    HostOSArchitecture = 1033
    FirmwareType = UEFI
    BiosReleaseDate = 20200620000000.000000+000
    BiosVendor = N2CET54W (1.37 )
    BiosVersion = N2CET54W (1.37 )
    HostOSVersion = 10.0.18363
    HostOSBuildString = 18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202
    TargetOSBuildString = 10.0.19041.568 (vb_release_svc_prod1.200929-2208)
    HostOSLanguageId = 
    HostOSEdition = Enterprise
    RegisteredAV = Windows Defender
    FilterDrivers = FileInfo
    UpgradeStartTime = 15.11.2020 15:30:11
    UpgradeEndTime = 15.11.2020 16:13:43
    UpgradeElapsedTime = 00:43:32
    CV = 4zV5tAA0J0Oq5Zcl
    ReportId = 


Error: SetupDiag reports rollback failure found.
Last Phase = Post First Boot
Last Operation = First boot apply
Error = 0x8007001F-0x3000D
LogEntry: 2020-11-15 16:13:42, Error                 SP     Operation failed: First boot apply. Error: 0x8007001F[gle=0x000000b7]

Refer to "https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Debug/system-error-codes" for error information.

Last Setup Phase:
Phase Name: Post First Boot
    Phase Started: 15.11.2020 16:13:31
    Phase Ended: 01.01.0001 0:00:00
    Phase Time Delta: 00:00:00
    Completed Successfully? False


Last Setup Operation:
Operation Name: First boot apply
    Operation Started: 15.11.2020 16:13:31
    Operation Ended: 01.01.0001 0:00:00
    Operation Time Delta: 0:00:00:00,0000000
    Completed Successfully? False
```

Comment: [SetupDiag](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/setupdiag) is a very good tool.  Edit your question with the results.  What you have provided isn't that helpful.

Comment: [Your installation appears to be corrupt.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update-winpc/windows-10-creators-update-failure/22aed647-816b-4258-8efa-a31e1792e5ca) run SFC and DISM and edit your question with the relevant information from both

Comment: Has this update been offered by Windows Update, or did you force it?

Comment: @harrymc: The update was offered by Windows Update twice, then it ceased to be offered. The third time I used the Upgrade Assistant (as described above) to force it.

Comment: @harrymc - There are no hardware blocks to 20H2 at this time. The author also already answered your question by indicating that "Windows Update offered me Win10 upgrade from version 1909 to 20H2."

Comment: @Ramhound: I added the SetupDiag results to my question. Unfortunately, it found nothing. I'll try DISM and SFC. This will take more time, I have to ensure that I don't break anything, or that I will be able to rollback.

Comment: Perhaps you could try doing a Repair Install from  ISO while booting in Safe Mode.

Comment: @harrymc: I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: @Ramhound: Unfortunately, after fixing the filesystem problems with DISM and SFC, the upgrade failed with the same error. :-( Now, SFC cannot find any filesystem integrity problems. `setupact.log` contains almost identical records and exactly the same errors as before, so the filesystem corruption wasn't the cause of the problems.

Comment: Have you moved the user profile to another drive other than the system drive?

Comment: A Repair Install is no different from the upgrades that you already tried several times. It's not a clean install, just another attempt at doing the upgrade. See [this article](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: Yes, user profiles of normal users are on D:. Local admin profile is on C:. However, the error mentions "user with ID: USER00000005, SID: S-1-0-0", which seems to be Nobody.

Comment: @harrymc: This seems as a too big cannon to me, for now. I've changed too many settings, and I'm afraid that this would reset everything to default values. I'll do that only as a last resort. I hope still that the logs are sufficient for determining the cause of the failures.

Comment: @Ramhound: Success!!! Thank you for your invaluable advices and hints. Details in the Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by a bug in the Windows Upgrade script, that is there for years, and it is still not resolved. It occurs on computers where user profiles are not on the system disk. In my case, my system disk is C:, and user profiles are on D:.

To resolve this problem, open RegEdit and navigate to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`. Here, change `ProfilesDirectory` to the default value `C:\Users`. In my case, this was sufficient for the upgrade to succeed. After the successful upgrade, change `ProfilesDirectory` back to the previous value. Compare e.g. [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/45fc61ba-8ad0-4528-8cb7-ab1f4d4059da/upgrading-windows-10-1703-to-1709-fails-with-0x8007001f-firstboot-migratedata?forum=win10itprosetup).

Big thanks to @Ramhound! I hope Microsoft addresses this problem soon, because it causes headaches to many people (try searching internet).

Comment: Technically, moving the user profile is possible, but is an unsupported configuration.

Comment: Ramhound is right about that. This is not a bug.

Comment: This is a novelty in Win10, isn't it? In previous versions of Windows, moving user profiles to another disk was a well documented procedure.

Comment: The documentation is not clear about that: In https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/user-profiles-and-logon/relocation-of-users-and-programdata-directories they say "By changing the default location of the user profile directories or program data folders to a volume other than the system volume, **you cannot service** your Windows installation.", but "Beginning with Windows 10, OS upgrades are **supported even if** user profiles are redirected to another drive." In any case, the upgrade errors should be more clear about the cause of upgrade failure.

Comment: Hi,
in my case it was a failing user home migration during the upgrade from 1803 to 20h2:
  <FailureDetails>ErrCode = 3, MigOp = apply, MigObject = C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Eigene Musik [Beispielmusik.lnk][gle=0x00000003], Error = , LastOperation = OOBE boot apply, LastPhase = Pre OOBE Boot</FailureDetails>
I just deleted the link and the Desktop.ini in it. Same for My Videos etc.